# Erratic padding in React Native (with Expo)

Tags: react-native, flexbox, expo

I am trying to wrap my head around a weird phenomenon. Setting `paddingLeft` on a React Native view (an Expo project), the padding suddenly 'jumps'.

On the `containter` element, I set different values for `paddingLeft` (see code snippet further down).

## paddingLeft: 11

Up to 11, everything works as I would expect it.
[image]

## paddingLeft: 12

Going from 11 to 12, suddenly there is padding on both sides and the content become very slim
[image]

The structure of the view and the styling

```
    return(
        <View style={styles.constainer}>
            <Text style={styles.title}>{'some placehoder text'}</Text>
            <ScrollView 
                style={styles.scrollView}
                showsVerticalScrollIndicator={false}
                onScroll={saveScrollPosition}
                scrollEventThrottle={500}
                ref={scrollRef}
                >
                {lessonViews}
            </ScrollView>
        </View>
    )
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    constainer: {
        paddingLeft: 11
    }, 
    title: {
        ...typo.h1
    },
    scrollView: {
        height: '87%',
    }
})
```

Has anyone seen this before? What am I missing?

Comment: can you create an expo snack with a reproducible example?

Comment: Thanks @IanVasco! Putting together the snack helped me narrow down the problem. It turns out the `container` was missing a `flex: 1` which had the text push the width of the container. When `padding`got big enough to cause a line break in the text, that's where I saw the jump.